# Make a ROC plot with predefined AUC value

Tags: python, r, roc, auc

Is it possible to plot ROC curves in python or R for known AUC values?

I have a model that I cross validated and the cross validated AUC is 0,92 (std=0,02). Is there a way to simply visualise this AUC? (I know it’s possible to code it to plot the AUC immediately from the model but I would want to know if it’s possible to just plot a roc curve with a specific AUC and std - regardless of the model).

Comment: Yes, but it would be the wrong shape to represent your actual data. There are an infinite number of ROC curves with an AUC of 0.92.

Comment: Plotting a ROC curve requires a model and data.  Knowing the AUC isn't enough to define it.  Rather, the AUC is a single scalar value that's calculated from the ROC.

Comment: Okay thanks both of you, I understand now. I just thought that nobody actually cares about the shape as long as it is a high AUC.